# VSTS builds includes all previous commits as associated changes

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an issue that makes all my previous commits show as associated changes in each new build.  I believe the issue is related to the automatic triggering of the build definition using a wildcard branch pattern.  I trigger our release builds on any commits on a branch name with the pattern 'release/*'.  Each production release of our software starts with a new release branch with the following naming convention 'release/1', 'release/2', etc. where the number matches our released software version.

The problem is that when the 'release/2' build gets ran, the associated changes show all commits that lead up to 'release/2' including the commits that led up to 'release/1'.  This continues with every new release.

I thought the way that it was supposed to work, was to only show the changes that occurred between the current build and the previous successful build.

Any insight into this issue would be appreciated.

**Steps to reproduce this issue:**

1. In VSTS create a git repo w/ add readme
2. Create new build definition (empty), set 'Get Sources' step to the repo you just created and the branch to master

   - go to options and set 'Automatically link new work in this build' to enabled
   - go to 'Triggers' > Continuous Integration > Trigger Status > Enabled > Branch Filters > set Branch specification to 'release/*' (excluding single quotes)
3. Clone new repo to your computer
4. Create a file that will be used to make modifications in the repo, add and commit the file.  For example I will use ver.txt
5. Push updated master branch to server (`git push origin`)
6. Perform the first build by just queing it up through the VSTS build area of the project
7. Create first release branch

   - `git checkout -b release/1`
   - make modifications to ver.txt (I just increment the value)
   - `git commit -am "Updated to version 1"`
   - `git push origin release/1`
   - build should be triggered once this branch is pushed to the server
   - Once build is finished, view build Summary > Associated changes, notice that all commits for this new repo are listed
   - Merge release branch back into master

     - `git checkout master`
     - `git merge release/1`
     - `git branch -d release/1`
     - `git push origin -d release/1`
8. Create second release branch

   - `git checkout -b release/2`
   - make modifications to ver.txt (I just increment the value)
   - `git commit -am "Updated to version 2"`
   - `git push origin release/2`
   - build should be triggered once this branch is pushed to the server
9. At this point when looking at the latest builds' Associated changes you will see that it continues to cumulate the entire history of the repository
   as opposed to just the commits between the current build and the last successful build despite the fact that it is the same build definition being ran

Comment: What's the source you used? What're detail steps to reproduce this scenario?

Comment: I just revised my question that now includes the detailed steps to reproduce this issue.  I am using git btw. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find out the cause for this? I think I'm running into the same issue. When a new branch is created, it shows all previous commits (even before the branch) as changes. It also links all these with work items. Highly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It is also based on the source, not just build, so regarding release/2, it compares current build with last successful build of the release/2 branch source, so it includes the commit in release/1.

I recommend that you can merge changes through Pull Request with a successful build, and check the changes in this build. ([Branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies))

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on why the "Updated to version 1" commit that is already linked to the release/1 build, also redundantly (incorrectly in my mind) get's linked to the release/2 build?
Could you also explain what doing a pull request would do - and from where to where a pull request should be made?
Thanks