# Azure DevOps Linked Work Items in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

How does Azure DevOps identify linked workitems during pipeline (Azure DevOps YAML)?

I believe it is supposed to get only the workitems linked to new commits (i.e. commits which were not included in a previous pipeline)

However, it sometimes seems to link all work items. But this does not always happen. I did not manage to identify the pattern yet. But I noticed that when I do a change in the pipeline YAML, it seems to trigger this behaviour that links all work items again (even if they where linked to a previous commit and not to newly included commits).

## Updated to include additional information

#### This is my build pipeline YAML

```
name: 03.01.00$(Rev:.r)
pool:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  persistCredentials: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: MySol/MySol.sln

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: MySol/MySol.sln
  inputs:
    solution: MySol/MySol.sln
    vsVersion: 15.0

- task: WorkItemUpdater@2
  inputs:
    workitemsSource: 'Build'
    workItemType: 'Task,Bug'
    updateAssignedTo: 'Never'
    updateFields: 'Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild,v$(Build.BuildNumber)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
```

#### Pipeline settings:

**Processing od new run requests:** Enabled

**Automatically link work items included in this run:** checked & dev branch selected

---

#### Triggers:

**Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here:** checked

**Enable continuous integration:** checked

**Batch changes while a build is in progress:** unchecked

#### Branch filters

Included dev branch + another feature branch

#### Path filters

None

Comment: I tried the same thing, do a change in pipeline YAML and it just get only the work items linked to new commits. Can you provide a complete detailed description about the whole process so that we can reproduce this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I included some additional details in my question

Comment: Thanks for the detailed settings and sorry for late reply and the issue is not reproduced still. Please check the ["View X changes" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipe0E.png) in your run which reproduced the issue Summary, check the commits included and you shall find which commit(s) linked all the work items.

Comment: I checked and it seems to include all the commits somehow. Not sure why that's the case ...

Comment: This sounds just like when you create a pull request to merge branches and all the commits will be listed. According to [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368770/vsts-builds-includes-all-previous-commits-as-associated-changes), i would suggest you to create this pull request to merge your changes to see if the issue could be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Apologies, but I did not fully understand your suggestion. Do you mean that I should use Pull Requests and that should resolve the issue. We use Pull Requests when commiting the dev branch. However, I noticed that in this case (when pipeline included all commits), the build was triggered from a separate feat branch and hence was not subject to a Pull Request. I am not sure whether the problem is that the build triggered from a different branch. Or if the problem is because this different branch did not have a Pull Request.

Comment: We've had similar issues in the past when merging in multiple directions. That is, merging toward production and then down into sprint branches. IIRC, the solution was to cherry pick instead of merge.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: No, sorry - haven't resolved it